# Making a new spreadsheet using data from specific cells on a different spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I need help with an exercise spreadsheet I'm trying to make in excel. In my file I have 3 spreadsheets and one graph. The fist spreadsheet is called "Routine" and it has repeating tables with a section for date, exercise, weight, repetition, and a section for notes. The exercise column is linked to a different spreadsheet via data validation called "Exercise". On the "Exercise" spreadsheet I have a list of exercises and the muscle group those exercises work out. I was able to create a list linking the name of the exercise in this spreadsheet to a drop down box in the "Routine" spreadsheet.

What I would like to do now is have a new spreadsheet for just the raw data. I want to be able to enter a date on one of my tables, select an exercise with my drop down box and insert a weight. In the new spreadsheet for data I'd like it to automatically pull new data when I put a date in an unused table. Once I put the date in I would like to fill in the "Date" column and if record the weight in a set "Exercise". With this data I'd then like to have a line graph showing me my progress with the date in the horizontal axis and weight increase in the vertical axis. I'd like to also be able to select either a specific exercise or multiple exercises at any given time to be represented on the line graph. I am leaving a link to imgur when I have taken screenshots of what I've done so far.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUlHH.jpg

edit:
here is a new set of screenshots, I hope this better explains when I'm trying to accomplish.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw3YH.jpg

Thank you all in advance,
Mark

Comment: It sounds like you'd be wanting a vlookup or index/match?  This is a pretty broad question, you have more than one question in your post, could you perhaps break it down? What have you tried so far, and what hasn't worked? I see you have organized the data, but what have you tried vis-à-vis your main question?  It's a bunch wrapped into one, and just a point that SO is not a codewriting service.  Please check over [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips and suggestions.

Comment: To be honest so far the only thing I tried doing is equaling the one cell to the date cell and repeating that a few times then dragging the column down. This didn't give me the results I was looking for. I tried asking a friend of mine who is much more versed in excel than I am and he didn't know how to tackle this either so he suggested this site to me.

Comment: This is a great site for sure.  What can really get your question traction though is the additional info that you tried to do X, but couldn't. Or you tried Y, but don't understand Z about it, etc.  If you show effort on what you've tried, we're more than happy to help troubleshoot.  I'll take a look this afternoon though.  But really quick, check out [this page](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/), is that the sort of thing that you think you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading and this looks like it can be a big help. I do apologize that my original question isn't specific enough but I'm still a novice when it comes to excel. I brought up the vlookup with my friend and he seems to think its a good start, I'm also reading the article you sent me about index match which looks to be a good lead as well. Let me see if I can make my question more specific to what I am looking to do.

Comment: I just wanted to say again thank you for the help, I was able to solve my problem. I looked into doing the INDEX/MATCH combination but I was getting lost in it nor could my other friend who was helping me figure it out that way. I ended up finding a post with someone with a similar problem that I was having and someone gave him a solution. I adopted that equation and turned it into something I could use and the end result was this.

Comment: =IF(OFFSET(Routine!$B$2,(ROW()-2)*12,0)=$V$1,OFFSET(Routine!$F$2,(ROW()-2)*12,0),IF(OFFSET(Routine!$B$5,(ROW()-2)*12,0)=$V$1,OFFSET(Routine!$F$5,(ROW()-2)*12,0),IF(OFFSET(Routine!$B$8,(ROW()-2)*12,0)=$V$1,OFFSET(Routine!$F$8,(ROW()-2)*12,0),IF(OFFSET(Routine!$B$11,(ROW()-2)*12,0)=$V$1,OFFSET(Routine!$F$11,(ROW()-2)*12,0),""))))